# Plotting same results in JMeter as ApacheBench

Tags: jmeter, apachebench

We are benchmarking our server and therefor we are using multiple benchmark tools. We already used ApacheBench giving us some great results and were also easy to plot in a graph.

[Example plot AB results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGXzn.jpg)

Now we are using JMeter but having a hard time to get a good plot. We would love to have almost (completely) the same plo as the one from AB. So response time vs. requests. We tried already every listener but haven't found any satisfactory result.
We are using JMeter 2.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** Isn't [Response Time Graph](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Time_Graph) what you're looking for?

**Option 2:** It's possible to build any graph from JMeter .jtl CSV or XML results file using Excel or equivalent, Google Charts API, JFreeChart, Javascript, etc.

**Option 3:** There is a [JMeter Listener](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/83191-blazemeter-plugin-to-jmeter) which automatically builds pretty and professional looking graphs for your performance test and have results comparison killer-feature

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- Core Response time graph
- Jmeter plugins : http://jmeter-plugins.org which has a lot of nice and very useful graphs which will meet your needs ( response time, percentiles, distribution, response codes per second ...)